# Why is PIP not upgrading the Package

Tags: python, pip

Why is `pip` not installing the LATEST? Is there a way to force LATEST?

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade pefile
Requirement already up-to-date: pefile in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...

$ pip show pefile
---
Name: pefile
Version: 1.2.10-114
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires:

$ pip search "pefile"
pefile                    - Python PE parsing module
  INSTALLED: 1.2.10-114
  LATEST:    1.2.10-139

$ sudo pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --pre pefile 
Downloading/unpacking pefile
  Downloading pefile-1.2.10-114.tar.gz (49kB): 49kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/pefile/setup.py) egg_info for package pefile

Installing collected packages: pefile
  Found existing installation: pefile 1.2.10-114
    Uninstalling pefile:
      Successfully uninstalled pefile
  Running setup.py install for pefile

Successfully installed pefile
Cleaning up...
```

Note:

```
$ pip list
pefile (1.2.10-114)
pip (1.5.6)
```

References:
https://code.google.com/p/pefile/

Comment: When all else fails and time is pressing, nuke the current install of the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the `pefile` pages for [`1.2.10-114`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pefile/1.2.10-114) and [`1.2.10-139`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pefile/1.2.10-139) - you'll see an important difference, the latter doesn't have a "Files" section with a source and egg. That means that the files are hosted externally and you need to allow `pip` to install from an *[external](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_wheel.html#cmdoption--allow-external) and [unverified](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_wheel.html#cmdoption--allow-unverified) source*:

```
pip install pefile --upgrade --allow-external=pefile --allow-unverified=pefile
```

Demo:

```
$ pip show pefile
---
Name: pefile
Version: 1.2.10-114

$ pip install pefile --upgrade --allow-external=pefile --allow-unverified=pefile
pefile an externally hosted file and may be unreliable
pefile is potentially insecure and unverifiable.
...
Installing collected packages: pefile
  Found existing installation: pefile 1.2.10-114
    Uninstalling pefile:
      Successfully uninstalled pefile
  Running setup.py install for pefile

Successfully installed pefile
Cleaning up...

$ pip show pefile
---
Name: pefile
Version: 1.2.10-139
```